# Converting bitmap Image to Uri not working

Tags: android, uri, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I am Using following code to convert bitmap Image to Uri

```
  public static  Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Its working fine in Devices above from Marshmellow but not working in below versions

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage
```

Mentioned above code in the method is returning null in case of failure.I  searched through the internet but could not get any rightful answer. Hoping for proper guidelines.

I am using karbon 5.1 (API 22)

Comment: which error occur

Comment: I am using karbon 5.1 (API 22) and  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage within Method returns null instead of String

Comment: @pskink i am aspecting path and its returning null this is the case which is not letting Uri.parse to return Uri

Answer (score 0):

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage is actually accessing external storage to save the image.
Some important reminders which might be causing your app to fail:

1. A USB connection will block SD card usage if in Mass Storage mode.
2. There may be other factors that might lead to an SD card being inaccessible, so make sure that you can access the SD card using a file browser first.
3. Make sure that your permissions are correctly configured with android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: i have included above permission in runtime and in permission would you please elaborate point 1 and 2 since i have bitmap instance and passing in getImageUri method